# Custom cast button to cast videos on chromecast device

Tags: android, titanium

I am working for a titanium android module for cast functionality on chromecast device. Chromecast document says you can implement cast functionality using menu bar cast icon but titanium android module is not supporting the menu bar. So is there any way to implement cast functionality using a custom button. Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ali but link you send says "Note this sample app does not control a Google Cast device like Chromecast; it is only meant to show how to add a Cast button to an Android app"

Comment: That sample is not a complete sample that would cast a video or so; it shows how you can add a cast button to your application by using either the MediaRouteActionProvider or by using MediaRouteButton; the latter is what you are looking for; so as long as you can add a cast button to your app that can do the discovery, the rest would be handled by your application's logic (i.e. what to do with a route when it is discovered).